# Session cookies life time

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

Hi I try to use php sessions and I want to set the cookie's lifetime.
I try this code

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime','60');
```

But my Max-Age paramters is always "Session" and it doesn't have an expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

`session.cookie_lifetime` affects how long the server will remember the session. `Max-Age: session` refers to the length of the PHPSESSID cookie on the client machine.

[`session_set_cookie_params(60)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) will give the cookie a TTL of 60.

Comment: In my laoyot page, under the session_start() command I try your code in this way
<?php session_start(); session_set_cookie_params(time()+120);?>
But it doesn't work, session max-age is always "Session"